# Use Service from Module in another service

Tags: angular

i want to use a service in another service. if i import the service, the code will run. But now i moved the service to a module and i want to import the new module. but now can angular dont find the service.

New Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { LoginService } from './login.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule, FormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [ // components for use in THIS module

    ],
    exports: [ // components that we want to make available

    ],
    providers: [ // singleton services
        LoginService            
    ]
})
export class LoginModule { }
```

My second Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginService } from '../login/login.service'; // this works
import { LoginModule } from '../login/login.module'; // here angular can't find LoginService
...

@Injectable()
export class ImportService {
     constructor(private http: Http, private loginService: LoginService) { }
     ...
}
```

Can someone help me to fix the problem?

Comment: there is no problem in what you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second service, importing `login.service` is the right way to do it:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginService } from '../login/login.service'; // this works
...

@Injectable()
export class ImportService {
     constructor(private http: Http, private loginService: LoginService) { }
     ...
}
```

If it already works, that's great.

Comment: This answer completely misses the point that he needs to import his new `LoginModule` into the app module.

Comment: Oops, good point. I missed that. Yes, definitely need to import the module.